# How to use SIFT descriptors with Locality Sensitive Hashing?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

LSH is used with binary strings and is very efficient in indexing and retrieval. While SIFT is not a binary descriptor, it is still the best descriptor available there. Is it possible to use SIFT with LSH ? Also, are there better indexing techniques available for SIFT features ?

I have tried using SIFT with FLANNBased Matcher with LSH in OpenCV, but get the following error:

> what():  C:\OpenCV\opencv\modules\flann\src\miniflann.cpp:315: error:
>   (-210) type=5 in function buildIndex_

Code:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FlannBasedMatcher> matcher = new cv::FlannBasedMatcher(new cv::flann::LshIndexParams(5, 24, 2));
        matcher->match( descriptors, descriptors1, matches );
```

Note: This question was more apt at dsp.stackexchange.com, but it is in read only mode right now.

Comment: SIFT is indeed the best descriptor in view-point changes, but BRIEF outperforms it in photometric changes.

Also, I think that if you'll add a rotation compensation mechanism to BRIEF, it will give nice results in view-point changes.

Answer (score 3):

LSH is an algorithm of *dimensionality reduction* that outputs *binary strings*. It was designed to index real-valued, high-dimensional data (but with an intrinsic lower dimensionality, such as manifolds) with binary codes.

You can try to implement LSH by yourself so that it can work with SIFT descriptors. The naive and easiest way of doing it would be to use random projections, but some more clever scheme using the fact that a SIFT descriptor is an aggregate of gradient orientation histograms can probably be exploited to produce a more efficient hash function.

Comment: "Random projection in dimensionality reduction:
Applications to image and text data"
http://users.ics.aalto.fi/ella/publications/randproj_kdd.pdf

Comment: Do you know of any code sample available for using SIFT (or any such technique) with LSH

Comment: No, there's none. But taking a projection is just the application of a scalar product. Random projection means that you can choose a random hyperplane, and then it's just a matter of vector pointwise multipication.

Answer (score 3):

The two best indexing techniques used for SIFT are [kd-tree and k-means](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_visapp09.pdf), try them.
Both of them are implemented in [FLANN matcher which is part of OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html). 
This two papers compares FLANN and LSH for SIFTs:

"[Locality sensitive hashing: a comparison of hash function types and querying mechanisms](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/56/71/91/PDF/paper.pdf)"

"[How to Use SIFT Vectors to Analyze an Image with Database Templates](http://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~cohen/mypapers/auclairAMR07.pdf)"

Actually, Alexandr Andoni have implemented [something very similar](http://web.mit.edu/andoni/www/LSH/) to what you want.

Comment: but isn't LSH faster ?

Comment: It is, but less accurate. State-of-art image retrieval systems, as far, as I know, use k-means clustering.

Comment: thanks for the paper references. I am conceptually able to now understand what is happening, but really in a blind over how to code it

Comment: I think, "how to implement computer vision algorithm from the scratch" is not SO question. and, of course, it isn`t too easy.
You can ask this guy http://web.mit.edu/andoni/www/, he has already implemented it: http://web.mit.edu/andoni/www/LSH/

Comment: I was not looking for implementation from scratch. But I am not able to understand how to use his implementation along with SIFT.